# How do I select an ambiguous column reference?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here's some sample code illustrating what I'm trying to do. There is a dataframe with columns `companyid` and `companyId`. I want to select `companyId`, but the reference is ambiguous. How do I unambiguously select the correct column?

```
>> data = [Row(companyId=1, companyid=2, company="Hello world industries")]
>> df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF()
>> df.createOrReplaceTempView('my_df')
>> spark.sql("SELECT companyid FROM mcl_df")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark22/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 603, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/opt/spark22/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark22/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Reference 'companyid' is ambiguous, could be: companyid#1L, companyid#2L.; line 1 pos 7"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution ended up being pretty simple. Prior to running the SELECT statement I ran the following:

`spark.sql('set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true')`

Comment: You are a saviour!